# Using Python commenting xml tags

Tags: python, xml

For the below xml file, how can I comment(in xml) the heading tag including its children using Python? I tried using lxml but only able to add a new comment, not able to comment existing tags.

```
<note>
<to>Tove</to>
<from>Jani</from>
<heading> Reminder
    <security>level  1</security>
</heading>
<body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>
</note>
```

I would want the output to be like

```
<note>
<to>Tove</to>
<from>Jani</from>
<!--  <heading> Reminder
    <security>level  1</security>
</heading> -->
<body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>
</note>
```

Comment: Please show your efforts so far. It will make it easier for anyone to help you.

Answer (score 0):

> Comments in Python start with the hash character, `#`, and extend to
> the end of the physical line. A comment may appear at the start of a
> line or following whitespace or code, but not within a string literal.
> A hash character within a string literal is just a hash character.
> Since comments are to clarify code and are not interpreted by Python,
> they may be omitted when typing in examples.

```
<note>
<to>Tove</to>
<from>Jani</from>
#<heading> Reminder
#    <security>level  1</security>
#</heading>
<body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>
</note>
```

Here is a link to [An Informal Introduction to Python](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/introduction.html).

Answer (score 0):

Try something like

```
with open('test.xml', 'r+') as f:
lines = f.readlines()
f.seek(0)
f.truncate()
for line in lines:
    if '<heading>' or '</heading>' in line :
            line = line.replace('<heading>', '<-- <heading>').replace('</heading>', '</heading> -->')
    f.write(line)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example using the built-in ElementTree library and your xml sample as the input file:

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree as et

tree = et.parse('test.xml')
note = tree.getroot()

# Locate the heading and preserve the whitespace after the closing tag
heading = note.find('heading')
tail = heading.tail

# Generate the comment string with a space before and after it.
heading.tail = ' '
heading_comment = ' ' + et.tostring(heading,'unicode')

# Generate the comment node with the text of the commented out node and its original whitespace tail.
comment = et.Comment(heading_comment)
comment.tail = tail

# Locate the location in the child list of the heading node,
# remove it, and replace with the comment node.
index = note.getchildren().index(heading)
note.remove(heading)
note.insert(index,comment)

tree.write('out.xml')
```

Output file:

```
<note>
<to>Tove</to>
<from>Jani</from>
<!-- <heading> Reminder
    <security>level  1</security>
</heading> -->
<body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>
</note>
```